# VisionOS - visually detached view

Tags: swiftui, visionos

In VisionOS app, I would like co create a view, that is visually detached from the main window, but stays on specified location relatively to the window. In short, I would like something like this (screenshot from wwdc video):
[image]

I can create another window, but I could not find a way to specify its 3d location. I also found .toolbar() modifier with .bottomOrnament placement, but there are very limited options for positioning, and also size. My view would be bigger and more complicated, not just menu of buttons.

What is the recommended way of doing such thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create ornaments (swiftUI view) and add a spacer to it:

```
.ornament( visibility: showOrnaments ? .visible : .hidden, attachmentAnchor: .scene(_: .bottom)) {
   Spacer(minLength: 10)
   ThumbnailOrnament()
    }
  .fixedSize()
```

Comment: .fixedSize() shrunk my main window content, removing it made it ok